# Debugging production uglified javascript

Tags: javascript, exception, error-reporting

I am trying to create a javascript error reporting system. The aim of the system is to collect info when an exception occurs and notify our servers. The problem is that in production the code is uglified and concatenated on the server side. thus any line numbers or file names are useless. I was wondering what is the best way to proceed to collect the required info. The javascript code will be running on the browsers of the users of our software so source maps are not effective since there is very little browser support for now.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://github.com/occ/TraceKit

Comment: Actually yes it did help together with serving unuglified code however concatenated. It shows the context of the error so it helped alot.